# How can I trigger my iPhone's alarm on receipt of an SMS message?

Tags: iphone, remote-control, alarm

I want to give certain people the ability to wake me up by sending an SMS message (e.g. "Wake Up!") to me, even when Do Not Disturb is on.  Is there a utility that makes this possible, or an app that already does something similar?

Answer (score 3):

If you mark those people as "VIP's" on your phone, then their text messages will sound even when the Do Not Disturb mode is one.

Comment: But what if I wanted an alarm to trigger, so I can be sure to wake up?